# Js Errors After Loading to Server

Tags: javascript, three.js, syntax-error

In the body of my page I am calling JS files that are hosted on dropbox, but I am getting error messages in the inspector and the JS is not running (a three.js shader should be visible but all that shows is the page background color.)

When hosted locally, the JS and website work perfectly. It is only after moving them online that it stopped working and started firing off errors.

Does anyone know how to get this work? And how to get rid of these errors?

Thanks in advance.

link: http://artserv.webflow.io/

errors:[errors logged in console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4zm9e.jpg)

Comment: don't see any `three.js` file added to your page :(

Comment: a link to a site and a picture of errors? ... See [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @TheVillageIdiot ah oversight. it has been added in but still same errors. :(

Comment: @jaromanda : the error messages, replicate-able in-console, are my concern. It seemed more considerate to provide a link when I actually don't know what js is causing the issue and thus cannot provide it for you here. jeezus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems you are getting the development version of files or files from node_modules pushed/included in your page.

The included `canvasrenderer.js` from *Dropbox* requires other files as stated in its `import` statements. So, it will throw up errors when you try calling functions on it.

Instead of your dropbox source, try adding files with this code to see if it works:

```
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/mrdoob/three.js/master/build/three.min.js">    </script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/mrdoob/three.js/master/examples/js/renderers/CanvasRenderer.js"></script>
```

If you can edit the code, try using `WebGLRenderer` as shown in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gsa012Lc/13/).

```
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias: true, alpha: true});
```

Moreover, the performance is way better with **WebGL** one.

Comment: thank you so much that worked like a charm. Had not even considered the import statements.